# adding event listener with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-listener

So I would like to know when one of my variable changes in the html side.
But I couldn't find any way to use event listener ($watch) on my angular controller.

So, here is the problem that I am trying to fix:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Please Select the Device</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="reportCtrl.selectedDevice" ng-options="item.name as item.MyName for item in reportCtrl.deviceList">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" ng-if="reportCtrl.selectedDevice">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Please Select the Sensor</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <select class="form-control">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I fill the options with device list, depending on what user selects, I need to make another call to get all the sensor properties within that device, but I would like to make the call whenever user picks the device.

So how can I use event listener in this case to make my call??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use ng-change as the trigger for making the call. When you get your response, your 2nd select will update its options automatically (after you add in the ng-options attribute, of course).

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="doTheThing()" ng-model="reportCtrl.selectedDevice" ng-options="item.name as item.MyName for item in reportCtrl.deviceList">
```

You could alternatively use a $watch, but it's less efficient than ng-change in this case. `$scope.$watch('reportCtrl.selectedDevice', function(newValue, oldValue){...});`